# processes only terminate, when threads are terminated?

Tags: multithreading, process, pthreads

> Processes should only terminate themselves, when all their threads are
>   terminated!

It's a question in our mock exam, and we aren't sure whether the statement is true or false.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Is there a reason this has the 'c' tag?  There's no 'c' code in the question.

Comment: How is "Processes should only terminate themselves…" supposed to be read here? As "Is this what happens?" or "Is this the way programs should be written?"

Comment: We are learning C in this module

Comment: @duskwuff as it should be written

Comment: @xXMariusXx: If you learn about native C threads, pthreads or threads in general. Only for first the C tag is relevant. Said that, as the question is written as recommendation, it's certainly not wrong. In fact, even phrased as "shall", it would be. The question is who is responsible for termination. As it should be clear now, this is a typical exam question and can't be answered satisfactorily without the context.

Comment: So you're sure this is about POSIX threads?

Comment: I can't add context because there is no context. I just have to pick right or wrong 

Comment: we only used pthreads in this module, yes

Comment: @xXMariusXx I have revised my answer now that I know you're specifically being asked about pthreads.

Answer (score 0):

First, I need to point out that this exam question contains an incorrect presumption.  A running process *always* has at least one thread.  The initial thread, the thread that first calls `main` or equivalent, isn't special; it's just like every other thread created by `pthread_create` or equivalent.  Once all of the threads within a process have exited, the process can't do anything anymore — there's no way for it to execute even a single additional CPU instruction.  In practice, the operating system will terminate the process at that point.

Second, as was pointed out in the comments on the question, the use of "should" makes your exam question ambiguous.  It could be read as either "Processes only terminate when all of their threads are terminated" — as a *description* of how the system works.  Or it could be read as "You, the programmer, should write code that ensures that your processes only terminate when all of their threads are terminated" — as a *prescription* for writing correct code.

If you are specifically talking about POSIX threads ("pthreads"), the answer to the *descriptive* question is that it depends on how each thread terminates.  If all threads terminate by calling `pthread_exit` or by being cancelled, the process will survive until the last thread terminates, no matter which order they exit in.  On the other hand, if any thread calls `exit` or `_exit`, or receives a fatal signal, that will immediately terminate the entire process, no matter how many threads are still active.  (I am not 100% sure about this, but I *think* it doesn't matter whether any threads have been detached.)

There's an additional complication, which is that returning from a function passed to `pthread_create` is equivalent to calling `pthread_exit` for that thread, but returning from `main` is equivalent to calling `exit`.  That makes the initial thread a little bit special: unless you specifically end `main` by calling `pthread_exit`, the entire process will be terminated when the initial thread exits.  But technically this is not a property of the thread itself, but of the code running in that thread.

I do not know the answer to the *descriptive* question for threads libraries other than POSIX; in particular I don't know the answer for either Windows native threads, or for the threads library added to ISO C in its 2011 revision.

The answer to the *prescriptive* question is yes with exceptions.  You, a programmer, should write programs that, under normal conditions, take care to end their process only when all of their threads have finished their work.  (With POSIX threads, this translates to making sure that `main` does not return until all the other threads have been joined.)  However, sometimes you have a few threads that run an infinite loop, without holding any locks or anything, and there's no good way to tell them to exit when everything else is done; as long as exiting the process out from under them won't damage any persistent state, go ahead and exit the process out from under them.  (This is the intended use case for detached threads.)  Also, it's OK, and often the best choice, to terminate the entire process abruptly if you encounter some kind of unrecoverable error.   Those are the only exceptions I can think of off the top of my head.